# An extension of the Cauchy's 1st theorem type on limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Cauchy's Theorem-For a real positive term sequence $({a_n})$ such that  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a, \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}=a$. This is related to arithmetic mean. A similar theorem exists for geometric means with the equality as follows $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(\prod_{i=1}^na_i)^\frac{1}{n}}=a.$ My case is an extension to harmonic means as follows.
$$Proposition$$For a positive term sequence $(a_n)$ that converges to $a>0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}=a.$
$$Suggested\,proof$$Define a sequence $(b_n)\equiv(\frac{1}{a_i}-\frac{1}{a}).$ By algebra of sequences, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0.$ Clearly, $\frac{1}{a_i}=b_i+\frac{1}{a}.$ Summing up from $i=1$ to $i=n$ and dividing through by $n$ gives $H'_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nb_i}{n}+\frac{1}{a}.$ Clearly, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}H'_n=\frac{1}{a}$ by application of Cauchy's First Theorem on Limits on $(b_n).$ Further define $H_n\equiv\frac{1}{H'_n}.$ Also by algebra of sequences $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}H_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{H'_n}=a$ as was to be shown.
$$\\$$ The questions is: Is this line of proof okay?$$\\$$Any comments?

Comment: Simpler: Apply the first theorem to $b_i  = 1/a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your claim that $\frac{1}{a_{i}}=b+\frac{1}{b_{i}}$ might be incorrect, as I don't think such a constant $b$ exists. Otherwise you'd get
$$b+\frac{1}{b_{i}} = \frac{1}{a_i} = b_i + \frac{1}{a}$$
$$C + \frac{1}{b_i} = b_i$$
for a constant $C$ and taking derivatives gets a contradiction. I've detailed an alternative proof below.

---

Since $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=a$, clearly for $a > 0$ we have $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a_{i}}=\frac{1}{a}$.
Thus by Cauchy's Theorem $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}}{n}=\frac{1}{a}$$
If we let $f(x) = x^{-1}$, then $f$ is continuous at $\frac{1}{a}$ and hence preserves the limit of the sequence. Consequently
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}}{n})=f(\frac{1}{a})$$
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}}=a$$
Thus concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks. Your way is easier. I've seen the typing error and edited.